# Написание библиотеки

Tags: c, c++, библиотеки

Здравствуйте!

Часто вижу библиотеки, в которых есть только декларация функций, а объявление где-то запрятано. Например, есть библиотека, которая объявляет класс. Только где он объявлен, не видно. Как это делается?

Comment: Ну, если под декларированием Вы понимаете описание в *.hpp, то реализация должна быть в *.cpp файле. То есть если библиотека объявлена в файле Foo.h? то реализация находится в файле Foo.cpp или в какой либо dll, в какой именно смотреть по декларации.

Comment: Ну, а файла .cpp нет. Есть только какой-то .a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

О, нашел: http://www.techytalk.info/c-cplusplus-library-programming-on-linux-part-one-static-libraries/comment-page-1/. Только кроссплатформенно ли это?

```
#ifndef EGE_H
#define EGE_H

void doStuff();

#endif //EGE_H
```

Вот так как-то получается. А вот makefile:

```
makelib:
    g++ -Wall -I ./include/ -c ./src/*.cpp
    ar rcs ./lib/libEGE.a ./*.o
all:
    g++ -I ./include/ -L ./lib/ -lEGE -o ege_test main.cpp
```

Comment: Ну, может, покажете кусочек Вашего hpp файла?

Comment: @abalckin, обновил

Comment: Это нативный способ сборки статической библиотеки под nix (т.е. в Unix и Linux). Для Windows из коробки это работать не будет, нужно ставить и настраивать специальный пакет nix утилит - MinGW (который стоит или с которым готовы разбираться лишь у небольшое из числа Windows разработчиков). Поэтому, правильный способ сборки для Unix и Linux как описали вы выше, а для Windows лучше использовать средства предоставляемые VisualStudio.

Comment: @Xmaster, ИМХО, проект для VS - слишком жирно, bat-файла для компиляции инструментами студии будет вполне достаточно.

Comment: @insolor, насоветуют тут. Если уж серьезно разрабатывать библиотеку, то лучше воспользоваться кросс-платформенной системой сборки, вроде [CMake][1] или [GYP][2].


  [1]: http://www.cmake.org/
  [2]: https://code.google.com/p/gyp/